# Under suitable assumptions (listed in post), $\dim(R) = \dim(R_f)$ (Krull dimension), so where is the flaw in this argument?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $R$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra, $f \in R$ nonzero. Assume $R$ is a domain. I understand how to show that $\dim(R_f) = \dim(R)$, but I began exploring the following argument, and there is a mistake somewhere since it gives a different answer. Dimension in this problem means Krull dimension.

Now $R_f$ is a domain, and since $R_f \simeq R[X]/\langle 1 - fX \rangle$, $\langle 1 - fX\rangle$ is prime. Since $R[X]$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra and a domain, we have
\begin{equation}
    \dim(R[X]_{\langle 1 - fX \rangle}) + \dim(R[X]/\langle1 - fX\rangle) = \dim(R[X]).
\end{equation}
We have the tower of fields $k \subset \text{Frac}(R) \subset R(X)$, and
\begin{align}
    \dim(R[X]) & = \text{tr.deg.}_k(R(X)) \\
        &= \text{tr.deg.}_k(\text{Frac}(R)) + \text{tr.deg.}_{\text{Frac}(R)}(R(X)) \\
     &= \dim(R) + \text{tr.deg.}_{\text{Frac}(R)}(R(X)).
\end{align}
But $R(X) = \text{Frac}(R)(X)$, so $\text{tr.deg.}_{\text{Frac}(R)}(R(X)) = 1$. Since again $R_f \simeq R[X]/\langle 1- fX \rangle$, we thus have
\begin{equation}
     \dim(R[X]_{\langle 1 - fX \rangle}) + \dim(R_f) = \dim(R) + 1.
\end{equation}
Now $\langle 1 - fX \rangle R[X]_{\langle 1- fX \rangle}$ is a prime ideal (in fact, maximal) in $R[X]_{\langle 1 - fX \rangle}$. But $R[X]_{\langle 1 - fX\rangle}$ is a domain, so we have the strictly increasing chain of prime ideals $0 \subsetneq \langle 1 - fX \rangle R[X]_{\langle 1- fX \rangle}$ in $R[X]_{\langle 1 - fX \rangle}$. Thus $\dim(R[X]_{\langle 1 - fX \rangle}) \geq 2$, and then $\dim(R_f)\leq \dim(R) - 1$. Help please thanks!

Comment: If you have a strict chain of prime ideals $P_0\subset P_1\subset\cdots \subset P_n$ in a ring $R$, $\dim R\geq n$. Using this, you only get $\dim(R[X]_{<1-f(X)>}\geq 1$, how did you get 2?

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thank you.